# Validation Rule at Closed Case

Tags: formula, validation-rule, case-object

I want two fields to be fill out when the user change the case to Status "Closed" and Sub-Status "Closed", if not filled out to don't allow them to save it until it is completed. I created this validation rule but when testing I am still able to save it and it does not prompt me to fill the fields. What am I doing wrong?

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Closed"),
    ISPICKVAL(Status_Sub_Stage__c,"Closed"),
    (
        ISBLANK(Implementation_Live_Date__c)
    ),
    (
        ISBLANK(Client_Kick_Off__c)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The nature of `AND()` means that if *any* of the conditions are false, then the entire result is false.

So if one of your two target fields are filled in, then the `ISBLANK()` returns false, and your validation rule doesn't trigger.

To make this work as intended, you want to check if either of your two target fields are blank. That means you need to wrap your two `ISBLANK()` checks in an `OR()` (the outermost function for your validation will still be `AND()`). That way, the only way for the `OR()` to return false is if *both* of your target fields are populated.

From a UX (User eXperience) point of view though, you should probably separate this into two validation rules so that you can get an error indicator (and message) next to both of those fields. With a single validation rule (that can only emit a single error message), you'd either need to put the error at the top of the page or choose one of the two fields to display it against (the latter being bad UX).

Comment: I tried it with only one field and the OR and it works but in each status instead of only one:AND (
OR(
ISPICKVAL( Status, "9 - Closed"),

ISBLANK(Implementation_Live_Date__c))
)